# Cordova - how to detect the app is not actively used anymore Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Okay, so my application is a flashlight/torch app found here:
https://github.com/Skelware/Fancy-Flashlight and it uses a Cordova plugin found here: https://github.com/Skelware/Cordova-Flashlight

Currently I only care about Android. To briefly explain the way an app like this works on Android: The app has to request access to the camera and this is done in the background, it takes a while before the camera is loaded and thus loading (and unloading) should happen as little as possible. While an app has access to the camera, no other app can request access.

When my app starts, it loads the camera and does what it needs to do. But when the user switches to a different app or closes my app, the camera is still registered to my app causing all other apps to be unable to use the camera.

Although I would prefer to handle this on the JavaScript side, it would also be okay to handle this natively in the plugin.

Window's unload event seems to be fired when exiting (fully exiting, that is) the app, but it doesn't have enough time to release the camera.

Cordova version is 4.0 and Android version is 4.4, although I doubt that would matter.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem on your case is that the app goes to sleep when it hits background mode (user presses home button etc.). This can be prevented with a [Cordova background plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) by calling

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
```

You can call this when you have acquired the camera and when you release it, you can call its counterpart

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disable();
```

This way you don't prevent the sleeping when not necessary, and thus you safe some battery.

Then, you need to simply bind the *pause* event

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
  // Here call your release function and in the release function, you can call the disable for background mode
}, false);
```

Comment: I think this is what I need, I will try it after dinner and if this does what I think it does I will accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: Oh, one glitch I noticed: The back button does not work anymore, have you had that happen before?

Comment: @StephanBijzitter: Adding this plugin should have nothing to do with that. Make sure, that your back button handler is working.

Comment: That's the point, I'm not interacting with the back button at all, this started happening after installing the plugin. However I fixed it by listening to the back button and using app.exitApp, but yeah, it was a bit strange

Comment: @StephanBijzitter: Actually, now that you mentioned it, I went to see the source code. The default handler for back button (which would kill the app) is disabled to prevent the app from getting killed which kind of makes sense for this kind of plugin that doesn't want let the app to be exited.

Comment: Yeah for most uses it makes sense, although in my specific case I just needed it to buy some time :-)